# How to trigger args.validationFailed in PrimeFaces oncomplete

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

When the `Save` button is pressed, the data from the *actionsDialog* should be validated. If the required information is entered and valid, a second dialog called *reasonDialog* would be displayed.

Non-JSF validation of the saved object is done with a method that returns a list of error messages. I case the validation fails the errors messages are displayed with FacesMessage. How should I do in `objectsBean.validate` to trigger the if else clause from `oncomplete`?

```
<p:dialog id="actionsDialog" widgetVar="actionsDialog" dynamic="true" 
    resizable="false" width="800" modal="true">
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/flows/custom-flow/genericObject.xhtml"/>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton value="Save" update="msgs"
            oncomplete="if (args.validationFailed) {reasonDialog.hide()} else {reasonDialog.show()}"
            actionListener="#{objectsBean.validate}"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true" oncomplete="actionsDialog.hide()" />
    </f:facet>
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If utilizing the JSF-builtin validation facility (i.e. just use validators which throw `ValidatorException` the usual way with therein the desired faces message) is really not an option for some reason (I'd really think twice, no, thrice about working around JSF validation facility), then you can always use [`FacesContext#validationFailed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#validationFailed%28%29) to signal JSF that the validation has failed in general, which is exactly what JSF validation facility is doing under the covers when a `ValidatorException` is caught.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
```

Comment: Either I do this or throw an Exception, the JSF lifecycle continues, it updates the model values and invoke the application. Is there a way to stop the rendering of the page when the validation fails?

Comment: @Mounir: This is not normal behavior. Just ask a question as instructed here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info so we can observe, debug and naildown your problem in case you're not up to that task.

Comment: I have the same behavior so far, I called FacesContext#validationFailed()  in actionListner of primafces command button version 5.3, JSF 2