# Oncomplete JavaScript does not re-evaluate EL expression at time of execution

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, el

I have a Primefaces dialog that contains a 'Save' button with the following oncomplete rules:

```
<p:dialog id="dialogId" widgetVar="dialogWidget">
     ...
    <p:commandButton value="Save" async="true"
                     oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed &amp;&amp; #{xp:hasNoMessagesToDisplay(dialogId)}) dialogWidget.hide()" 
                     partialSubmit="true" process="dialog"/> 

</p:dialog>
```

`#{xp:hasNoMessagesToDisplay}` is a custom EL function that checks to see if there are any FacesMessages associated for the dialogId specified. The problem is that the evaluation of this function only takes place when HTML is rendered for the dialog (e.g. on initial page load). I need the function to be evaluated when the oncomplete Javascript is evaluted (i.e. on the fly).

Is it possible to extend the Primefaces "args" Javascript object to include additional info, or what are alternative approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Got an idea from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401652/how-to-trigger-args-validationfailed-in-primefaces-oncomplete?rq=1) which gave me a solution:

Use `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();` when the FacesMessages for the dialog are created to indicate JSF validation failure so

`oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) dialogwidget.hide()"`

is sufficient. I'm not sure what implications this has, guess I'll just have to wait and see....