# Method should wait until window.open close

Tags: javascript, jsf

Am developing application in JSF. I have created `t:commandlink` that calls JavaScript method in `onclick` event, I have an action in same `t:commandlink`. That will trigger once `onclick` event complete. Before I used IE browser So, I used `window.openmodaldialog('sample.xhtml', '_blank');` to open popup in javascript like below,

```
<t:commandlink onclick="openPopup()" action="#{samplebean.savedata()}"></t:commandlink>
```

Javascript code:

```
function openPopup(){
  window.showmodaldialog('sample.xhtml', '_blank');
  return true;
}
```

In above code 'openPopup' method wait until showmodaldialog to close. Now am migrating application to Chrome browser. So, I used `window.open` since `window.showmodaldialog` is deprecated in Chrome. What am facing issue here is `openPopup` method not waiting until popup to close. It's getting executed and t:commandlink action block get called. How to make `openPopup` method to wait until popup close.

Comment: Then learn about ajax

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518381/proper-way-to-wait-for-one-function-to-finish-before-continuing) helps you

Answer (score 0):

try to switch to `oncomplete`, instead of `onclick`

Comment: Action should call after javascript method complete.

Comment: If it's a matter of openPopup should be called only if there's not problem in savedata, you could try like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401652/how-to-trigger-args-validationfailed-in-primefaces-oncomplete). You can also try to call openPopup server side, at the end of savedata function

Comment: You're right but before 50 rep i can't post comment ^^, now I use them