# p:autocomplete updating other parts of the page when complete-method called

Tags: primefaces

maybe I am missing something very basic.

I have a p:autocomplete with an p:ajax event="itemSelect" child and forceSelection="true"  attribute. 
When the user selects a value from the list I can update parts of the page from the itemSelect event. That works all fine. 
Now, I want also an page update when the user types something in the field. 
I would like to handle this as an unselect. 
Unfortunatedly I see no way to update when the complete-method is called. 
Even stuff like

```
final RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
requestContext.update("content_form:table");
```

in the complete-method does not help.

Any ideas? I hope I expressed myself in a comprehensive way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the *key* Events like onkeyup, onkeydown etc

```
        <h:panelGrid id="components2update">
            <ui:param name="teststuff" value="#{areasBean.someValueThatgotUpdated}" />
            <p:outputLabel value="#{teststuff}" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:autoComplete id="acSimple" value="#{someBean.someValue}"
            completeMethod="#{someBean.autoCompMethod}"
            .... >
            <p:ajax event="keyup" oncomplete="alert('ddd')"
                update=":#{p:component('components2update')}" />

        </p:autoComplete>
```

Comment: This does not work if you want to update something depending on the results of `autoCompMethod`. The `keyUp` event is being triggered before `autoCompMethod` is even called.

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic, sounds like you want to conditionally update your components, so you better handle that logic on a backing bean, and have it calling the update, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365094/can-i-update-a-jsf-component-from-a-jsf-backing-bean-method?rq=1