# Is it possible to stop perfoming validation after one of validators threw an exception

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

I have jsf-page:

```
<h:inputText>
   <f:validator binding="{validator}" />
</h:inputText />

<!-- some other inputs with validators -->
```

Is it possible to skip validation phase after one of the validators failed and render response with the only validation message?

Comment: The only way I can think of (and I am not an expert, just some creative guy) is to add a custom converter after each real converter that check if there was an error. If so, remove all input id's that still need to be processed from the FacesContext. How to actually try that is beyond the time I have/want to spend on creating answers. A little googling in tihs area might help and [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365094/can-i-update-a-jsf-component-from-a-jsf-backing-bean-method) might to

Comment: @Tiny Don't see how the asssociation is related here. If we skip the validation phase we skip the validation for the rest of the components.