# Display images without refreshing directory with JSF

Tags: jsf

In my project i create images and put them in a directory by :

```
 // Save process diagram to a file
            InputStream processDiagram = repositoryService.getProcessDiagram(processInstance.getProcessDefinitionId());
            try {
                FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(processDiagram, new File("/home/ilyass/selectSystemWorkspace/Core/selectsystem-view/src/main/webapp/images/workflow/Process11.png"));            
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    
            }
```

now i want to display it in my xhtml page using :

```
        <h:graphicImage value="/images/workflow/Process11.png" />
```

the problem is without refreshing the directory i can't retrieve the image ! i tried to add this line to my tomcat server.xml based on a solution found here : [Load images from outside of webapps / webcontext / deploy folder using  or  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-images-from-outside-of-webapps-webcontext-deploy-folder-using-hgraphi)

```
     <Context docBase="/home/ilyass/selectSystemWorkspace/workflow/" path="/workflow" />
```

But still the same since i'm creating the images inside the project and put them into the folder, any ideas how to solve that

Comment: i'm not using any db here ! i'm just creating an image puting it in PATH and then trying to display it in a JSF page

Comment: What you need is to refresh view (The graphic image) when image is saved refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367277/1460591

Comment: Isn't this a tomcat specific issue? And isn't the same a problem when using a plain html `img src=...` tag?

Comment: yes it's a server issue but not only tomcat , since i'm creating the images means that they're not presented to the server on first run . the image is set at the right path but only displayed in xhtml page after i refresh the directory where images are set