# How to reset inputText field in JSF Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

InputText field in the following dialog retains previous value even though I set it to blank before calling show(). The inputText field is only displayed blank when show() is called for the first time. My bean is session scoped.

```
<p:dialog id="dlgId" widgetVar="dlgVar" dynamic="true">
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1"> 
       <h:outputLabel for="nametext" value="Name" />
       <p:inputText id="nametext" value="#{myBean.name}" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{myBean.saveAction}" />
</h:form>
```

```
public void add(TreeNode selectedTreeNode) {
    setName("");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dlgVar').show()");
}

public void setName(String name) {
   this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
   return name;
}
```

How can I get the inputTEext field to display the value I set before calling show() rather then the value previously entered by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is: you need to update your form. To make it, you can use one of these solutions.

**Solution 1 : update it from your xhtml**

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1"> 
       <h:outputLabel for="nametext" value="Name" />
       <p:inputText id="nametext" value="#{myBean.name}" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{myBean.saveAction}" update=":form" />
</h:form>
```

**Solution 2 : update it from your managedBean**

*YourXhtml*

```
<h:form id="form">
...
</h:form>
```

*YourManagedBean*

```
public void saveAction() {
... 
name = ""; 
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":form");
}
```

You can also read this post [Can I update a JSF component from a JSF backing bean method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365094/can-i-update-a-jsf-component-from-a-jsf-backing-bean-method).

**Solution 3 : update it using an Ajax event**

You can also add an ajax event

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" type="button" >
    <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{myBean.saveAction}" update=":form"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: I tried both of your above suggestions and It is still not working. Let me explain further:
First time dialog displayed : InputText field is blank and the user enters "Mr Smith"
Second time dialog displayed: InputText field is "Mr Smith" and not blank which means user has to manually clear "Mr Smith" before entering a name.

Comment: where do you have to update your dialog 1. when you open the dialog or 2. when you click on saveAction ?!?

Comment: Good answer! just wrapped all possible alternatives.

Comment: @YagamiLight Thanks for your help - I used your first solution and it is working now. I have a same problem with another dialog in which I would like to set a predefined value before dialog is displayed rather then in action listener. Can this be done? i.e. call name ="some value" before calling show()..

Comment: @amah please make it as an answer and post a new question and i will look and try to give an answer

Comment: I have accepted your answer and also posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704050/how-to-display-dialog-with-default-values-in-primefaces