# how to update dynamic text in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm new to PrimeFaces (and JSF too) and I'm trying to update dialog message based on retrieved data.

View looks like:

```
    <p:dialog id="userDialog" header="Confirmation" widgetVar="userDialog" dynamic="true"  modal="true" closable="fasle" width="680px" resizable="false">
    <h:form>
        <b>Email address #{userListView.email}</b> is already registered with the following user <b>#{userListView.firstName}</b> <b>#{userListView.lasttName}</b>:

        <b>Please confirm that you would like to proceed with adding an additional account for this User.</b><br />
        <hr />
        <div class="ui-confirm-dialog-footer">
            <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="pi pi-check" onclick="PF('userDialog').hide()" />
            <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="pi pi-times" onclick="PF('userDialog').hide()" />
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

And controller looks like:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userListView")
@ViewScoped
public class UserListView extends DataTableListView implements Serializable {

 .....some other code...

    public String getFirstName() {

       String firstName = "";

       List<UserMembership> membershipList = getMembershipList();

       if (!membershipList.isEmpty()) {
           UserMembership membership = membershipList.get(0);
           firstName = membership.getUser().getFirstName();
       }

       return firstName;
    }

    public String getLasttName() {

       String lastName = "";

       List<UserMembership> membershipList = getMembershipList();

       if (!membershipList.isEmpty()) {
           UserMembership membership = membershipList.get(0);
           lastName = membership.getUser().getLastName();
       }

       return lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {

       String email = "";

       List<UserMembership> membershipList = getMembershipList();

        if (!membershipList.isEmpty()) {
            UserMembership membership = membershipList.get(0);
            email = membership.getUser().getEmail();
        }

        return email;
    }

 ....some other code...
}
```

and dialog box is spawned as

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("showDialog(userDialog')");
```

It will work fine for the first user but then when I will get that dialog box for another one it keeps data from first one not updated with current.

Also I have try to add

`onHide="PF('userDialog').content.empty()"`

to the dialog but that will remove whole dialog box content.

How can I destruct and refresh that dialog box with new data then?

PS.
Not sure if I need to get this done via

```
   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {}
```

Comment: Are you new to JSF as well?

Comment: @Kukeltje yeah - I'm PHP guy :D and welcome again!

Comment: There are several ways, but most importantly, it needs to be clear when and where you initiate the updating of the backing data? But start reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365094/can-i-update-a-jsf-component-from-a-jsf-backing-bean-method

Comment: OK. I have tried to use `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("userDialog");` just after `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("showDialog('userDialog')");` but that throws `ComponentNotFoundException`

Comment: Then that is not the **full client id** of the component (and for which there are multiple Q/A in  stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you are using Primefaces 7.0+ swap the already mentioned

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("userDialog");
```

for

```
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("userDialog");
```

If I can suggest you, set some id for `<h:form>` and use the full client ID after, something like

```
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("userDialog:yourFormId");
```

BalusC already answer a similar question in this thread [Can I update a JSF component from a JSF backing bean method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365094/can-i-update-a-jsf-component-from-a-jsf-backing-bean-method)

Comment: You **need** the id of the form (if there is one around the dialog), otherwise it won't work. The reference is always from the 'root'. But in this case the form is inside the dialog

Comment: Yes I know, the answer was for his case. Actually, if I'm not wrong, a form inside dialog it's ok. In scenarios where you use appendTo, he actually need to be inside.

Comment: Is there a way to update and then show instead having two lines which in Google Chrome sometimes will open `userDialog` twice one after another?

Comment: I'm not advanced JSF/Primefaces developer, but I guess you can't. But you can safely use 
PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("PF('userDialog').show()") and use the update after, the correct behavior doesn't show two dialog (remove onclick from the xhtml file, now your bean will show the dialog).

Comment: in case of old Primefaces version, just use the already known RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('userDialog').show()");

Answer (score 0):

In my case fix looks like

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":userDialog");
```

just after `.execute()` part.

Comment: Sure it does not wor without the colon? From my understanding it is automatically absolute (which is what the colon does)