# update outputtext from class

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax-update

I have a RichFaces project on JSF 2.2 and I wanted to show status updates and messages to the user while processing their request. I wanted to use a `a4j:outputpanel` with a simple outputext for this. I added a `system.out` line and it shows up on my server console when but the text on the screen is not updated.

In my process class:

```
private void showAdvise(final String message) {
   System.out.println(">>>>>ComUI showAdvise: " + message);
   this.beidCardStatusBean.updateStatus(message);
}
```

On my jsf page:
- I launch the proces with:

```
 <a style="font-size:150%;" onclick="startEID();" 
href="savePhoto.do?userId=#{detailUserBean.id}">#{UIMessages['button.loadPhoto']}</a>

<a:outputPanel id="eidPaneContainer" ajaxRendered="true">
  <rich:popupPanel header="EID" id="eidPane" width="100" height="80">
    <h:outputText id="eidStatus" value="#{beidCardStatusBean.getStatus()}" >
    </h:outputText>
  </rich:popupPanel>
</a:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Can you post more code? What does `startEID` do? How is the popuppanel being refreshed?

Comment: startEID function just opens the popuppanel:
<a:jsFunction name="startEID" render="eidPaneContainer" oncomplete="#{rich:component('eidPane')}.show()" />
The popuppanel isn't being refreshed when i call the showadvice function in my class which is the problem

Comment: See [how to render component from bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365094/can-i-update-a-jsf-component-from-a-jsf-backing-bean-method)

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the components the page has to send a request to the server, it doesn't happen automatically when something on the server changes. The easy solution is to use a poll, e.g.

```
<a4j:poll id="poll" interval="2000" enabled="#{bean.pollEnabled}" render="poll, popup" />
```

This will rerender the popup every 2 seconds. So in your case `startEID` needs to set `pollEnabled` and rerender the poll to start it.

PopupPanel might be a bit problematic when it comes to rerendering, try setting `domElementAttachment="parent"` if this doesn't work.