# To render JSF component from java class when we already know client id of that component

Tags: jsf

As per my code , I have to render jsf component clicking on radio button .so I have ajax event of Type 'click' , and want to add in the listener attribute that it has to render this jsf component. I have the client ID of that jsf component with me. planning to write the method in controller class.So how can I achieve this in java bean side?
any help is appreciable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I update a JSF component from a JSF backing bean method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365094/can-i-update-a-jsf-component-from-a-jsf-backing-bean-method)

Comment: So this code alone put into controller method FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add("clientID"); wont render jsf component.

Comment: Set the `rendered` attribute of the component you want to render and update its parent. But I must say, your question is to broad. Narrow it down to smaller issues and search on them. They all have been answered here on SO.